# Heart rate zones in people with blood disorders

Tags: heart-rate, metabolism

I have a type of anaemia, called thalassemia, a not too uncommon blood disorder which reduces the oxygen carrying capacity of the red blood cells. Therefore, when I exercise I have slightly elevated heart rate.

I am sure people here heard of the [heart rate zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heart_rate#/media/File:Exercise_zones_Fox_and_Haskell.svg). My problem is that when I exercise, I immediately hit to the anaerobic zone. If I am not careful, I can easily reach the maximum effort zone. However, I know that I am not really in maximum effort, because no one should be able to endure "maximum effort" for 50 mins. Also, I know that I am not really in "anaerobic zone", at least not 100% of the time, because anaerobic exercise for 50 mins should result in muscle aches due to the lactic acid build up.

I am checking up on my heart with a medical professional so you can assume the way I exercise is healthy for me. (But not necessarily to anyone else in this condition, so if you have a similar condition, do not assume that high heart rate exercise is okay for you.)

My questions is this: Is there a tentative way to know which zone I am in other than heart rate?